# Cannot get Proper Labels on PyPlot HeatMap from a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

Getting an error message when I try to render a heat map using this code below. This is just a way of testing this, I have much more involved application of to a large dataset about used cars...but I cannot even get past this issue with two pieces of data.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np

# initialize list of lists

#Putting in numbers for the "Name" data ends up working
#data = [[3, 10], [3, 15], [6,50]]

#initializing like this with actual strings for names gives the error
data = [["James", 10], ["Mary", 15], ["Emily", 14]]


# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 

# print dataframe. 
print(df)

plt.pyplot.pcolor(df, cmap='RdBu')
plt.pyplot.colorbar()
plt.pyplot.ylabel("Age")
plt.pyplot.xlabel("Name")
plt.pyplot.show()
```

The errors are as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/j/dataexploratory.py", line 22, in <module>
    plt.pyplot.colorbar()
  File "/home/j/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2320, in colorbar
    ret = gcf().colorbar(mappable, cax = cax, ax=ax, **kw)
  File "/home/j/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 2098, in colorbar
    cb = cbar.colorbar_factory(cax, mappable, **cb_kw)
  File "/home/j/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 1399, in colorbar_factory
    cb = Colorbar(cax, mappable, **kwargs)
  File "/home/j/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 945, in __init__
    ColorbarBase.__init__(self, ax, **kw)
  File "/home/j/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 327, in __init__
    self.draw_all()
  File "/home/j/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 349, in draw_all
    self._process_values()
  File "/home/j/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 703, in _process_values
    expander=0.1)
  File "/home/j/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2930, in nonsingular
    if (not np.isfinite(vmin)) or (not np.isfinite(vmax)):
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: Well, you can't create a heatmap from text data. You need numerical data. Also, with pandas, people normally use `df.plot....` instead of `plt...` in order to access pandas' wrapper around matplotlib.  [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html) is a good place to start exploring pandas and plotting.

Comment: I don't see why I can't make a heatmap like that.

The color of the cell is determined by the age of the individual. So all I need from the names data is to help label the tick marks on its axis.

Comment: Well, to show 1D data, a bar plot is used. A heatmap is for 2D data.  Just experiment around with `df.plot` and the options on the linked page.  Also, [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) has interesting options to draw elaborate heatmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Convert 'Name' to categorical dtype.